# Referring other vector containing boolean values to create another vector in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors in my dataframe df that are

```
a = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
b = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

and I want to create third one c such that

```
c = c(1, 0, 3, 4, 0)
```

which is b, but vanishes whenever element in a is FALSE.

I tried something like

```
df$c <- df$b[df$a == TRUE]
```

and it failed, so I made zero vector and tried to plug values of b in whenever a is TRUE,

```
zv = rep(0, 5)
df$c <- zv[...]
```

but don't know exact method here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can negate `a` to change `FALSE` to `TRUE` and assign those values to 0.

```
b[!a] <- 0
b
#[1] 1 0 3 4 0
```

---

We can also use `replace`

```
replace(b, !a, 0)
#[1] 1 0 3 4 0
```

---

Another approach could be to multiply `b` with `a` since `TRUE` is coerced to 1 and `FALSE` to 0.

```
b * a
```